# Issue with Double datatype in Scala

Tags: scala, double, precision

New to Scala and am trying to come up with a library in Scala to check if the double value being passed is of a certain precision and scale. What I noticed was that if the value being passed is 1.00001 then I get the value as that in my called function, but if the value being passed is 0.00001 then I get the value as 1.0E-5, Is there any way to preserve the number in Scala?

```
def checkPrecisionAndScaleFormat(precision: Int, scale: Int)(valueToCheck: Double): Boolean = {
  val value = BigDecimal(valueToCheck)
  value.precision <= precision && value.scale <= scale
}
```

Comment: `1.0E-5` is perfectly accurate and precise.

Comment: it is , but I need to check the precision and scale for that I need to capture the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I noticed was that if the value being passed is 1.00001 then I get the value as that in my called function, but if the value being passed is 0.00001 then I get the value as 1.0E-5

From your phrasing, it seems like you see `1.00001` and `1.0E-5` when debugging (either by printing or in the debugger). It's important to understand that

1. this doesn't correspond to any internal difference, it's just how [`Double.toString` is defined in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)).
2. when you do something like `val x = 1.00001`, the value isn't exactly 1.00001 but the closest number representable as a `Double`: 1.000010000000000065512040237081237137317657470703125. The easiest way to see the exact value is actually looking at [`BigDecimal.exact(valueToCheck)`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/math/BigDecimal$.html#exact(d:Double):scala.math.BigDecimal).

The only way to preserve the number is not to work with `Double` to begin with. If it's passed as a string, create the `BigDecimal` *from the string*. If it's the result of some calculations as a double, consider doing them on `BigDecimal`s instead. But string representation of a `Double` simply doesn't carry the information you want.